# How to give background color as white to HTML canvas image?

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas

I am trying to create a whiteboard in my MERN stack app.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import PermMediaIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PermMedia';

import './Whiteboard.css';

export default function Whiteboard({ canvasRef, socketRef }) {
    const params = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const colorsRef = useRef(null);
    const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
    const [canvasCurrent, setCanvasCurrent] = useState(null);
    const colors = document.getElementsByClassName('color');
    const [color,setColor]=useState('black')
    const onColorUpdate = (e) => {
        setColor(e.target.className.split(' ')[1]);
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        colors[i].addEventListener('click', onColorUpdate);
    }
    const [isDrawing, setIsDrawing] = useState(false);
  const [shapes, setShapes] = useState(
    JSON?.parse(localStorage?.getItem(`${params.workspaceId}-drawing`)) || []
  );
  const [currentStroke, setCurrentStroke] = useState([]);
    function drawShapes() {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        shapes.forEach((shape) => {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(shape?.points[0]?.x, shape?.points[0]?.y);
          shape.points.forEach((point) => {
            ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
          });
          ctx.strokeStyle = shape.color;
          ctx.lineWidth = shape.strokeWidth;
          ctx.stroke();
        });
    
        if (currentStroke.length > 0) {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(currentStroke[0].x, currentStroke[0].y);
          currentStroke.forEach((point) => {
            ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
          });
          ctx.strokeStyle = color;
          ctx.lineWidth = 2;
          ctx.stroke();
        }
    
        requestAnimationFrame(drawShapes);
      }
      useEffect(() => {
    drawShapes();
  }, [shapes, drawShapes]);
    socketRef.current.on('drawingChange', ({ drawingData }) => {
        localStorage?.setItem(`${params.workspaceId}-drawing`, JSON.stringify([...shapes,drawingData]));       
        setShapes([...shapes,drawingData]) 
            });
            socketRef.current.on('codeChange', ({ code }) => {
                localStorage?.setItem(`${params.workspaceId}-code`, code);
            });

    const clearCanvas = () => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.fillStyle = '#fff';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    };

    const downloadCanvas = () => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        console.log(canvas)
        setCanvasCurrent(canvas.toDataURL());
        const image = canvas.toDataURL('png');
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        const time = new Date();
        const imageName = time.toISOString();
        link.download = `${params.workspaceId}-${imageName}.png`;
        link.href = image;
        link.click();

        setTimeout(() => {
            const canvas = canvasRef.current;
            const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            
            const image = new Image();
            image.onload = function () {
              context.fillStyle='#fff'
                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
            };
            image.src = canvasCurrent;
        }, 2000);
    };
    function handleMouseDown(e) {
        // Start a new shape
        setIsDrawing(true);
        setCurrentStroke([{ x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY }]);
      }
    
      function handleMouseMove(e) {
        if (isDrawing) {
          setCurrentStroke([...currentStroke, { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY }]);
        }
      }
    
      function handleMouseUp() {
        setIsDrawing(false);
        const newShape = {
          type: "freehand",
          points: currentStroke,
          color: color,
          strokeWidth: 2
        };
        localStorage?.setItem(`${params.workspaceId}-drawing`, JSON.stringify([...shapes,newShape]));
        socketRef.current.emit('drawingChange', {
                        drawingData: newShape,
                        roomId: params.workspaceId,
                    });
        setShapes([...shapes, newShape]);
        setCurrentStroke([]);
      }
      function handleTouchStart(e) {
        handleMouseDown(e.touches[0]);
      }
      function handleTouchMove(e) {
        handleMouseMove(e.touches[0]);
      }
      function handleTouchEnd(e) {
        handleMouseUp(e);
      }
    return (
        <div>
            <canvas width={window.innerWidth}
      height={window.innerHeight}
      ref={canvasRef}
      onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
      onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
      onTouchStart={handleTouchStart}
      onTouchMove={handleTouchMove}
      onTouchEnd={handleTouchEnd} className='whiteboard' style={{backgroundColor:"white"}} />
            <div ref={colorsRef} className='colors'>
                <div className='color black' />
                <div className='color red' />
                <div className='color green' />
                <div className='color blue' />
                <div className='color yellow' />

                {/* Create a Tooltip with Erase */}
                <Tooltip title='Erase'>
                    <div className='color white' />
                </Tooltip>

                {/* Create a vertical line */}
                <div className='vertical-line' />

                {/* Create a ToolTip with IconButton to Clear */}
                <Tooltip title='Clear'>
                    <IconButton
                        onClick={clearCanvas}
                        className='clear'
                        aria-label='clear'
                        sx={{ color: '#03256C' }}
                    >
                        <DeleteIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>

                {/* Create a ToolTip with IconButton to Download */}
                <Tooltip title='Save as PNG'>
                    <IconButton
                        onClick={downloadCanvas}
                        className='download'
                        aria-label='download'
                        sx={{ color: '#03256C' }}
                    >
                        <PermMediaIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is my code. It is just a part of my code, because the whole code is too big.
In this whiteboard I have different colors of pen. And user can draw on canvas.

I am facing problem in download option.
On canvas the background color is white.
But, when user downloads his canvas, the background color in downloaded image comes out to be black.
How I can set the background color of downloaded image as white.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try adding `fillStyle` to different color? then clear it and then fill white.

```js
const clearCanvas = () => {
  const canvas = canvasRef.current;
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.fillStyle = '#ccc';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.fillStyle = '#fff';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
```